# Improving Efficiency of Java Code

Tags: java

I'm wondering if there are ways to improve the efficiency of the following code. (Or maybe there is a better algorithm?)

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int t = sc.nextInt();
for (int i = 0; i < t; i++){
  int m = sc.nextInt(), n = sc.nextInt(), maxM = 0, maxN = 0;
  for (int j = 0; j < m; j++){
    int newMonster = sc.nextInt();
    if (newMonster > maxM){
      maxM = newMonster;
    }
  }
  for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
    int newMonster = sc.nextInt();
    if (newMonster > maxN){
      maxN = newMonster;
    }
  }
  System.out.println(maxM >= maxN? "Godzilla": "MechaGodzilla");
}
```

Basically, I am reading in a bunch of numbers and want to find the maximum. For more detailed explanation of the original problem, please go to 
 https://open.kattis.com/problems/armystrengthhard/ 
The current code takes more than 1s to complete running, but I'm not sure which part (reading inputs or comparing numbers) takes more time.

Comment: with what input does it take 1s to complete? The small sample of your link or a bigger one? To find out if comparing numbers really impacts performance, just remove the 2 ifs from your 2 loops and see if it changes the processing time.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the inputs. I simply submitted this to the online judge. The first two test cases are really small so I passed them. But I failed on the third one. Hence, removing the if statements is not going to test the performance because it will not pass the first two small test cases.

Comment: One thing you can do to improve performance: don't declare any variable inside you for loops. Reading your link there can be 50*2*100000=10 millions integers to read. You can just use the same variable instead of allocating 10 millions int.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a CPU profiler to work out why it is spending so much CPU, however it is highly likely your program spends most of it's time performing IO operations i.e. `sc.nextInt()` or `System.out.println`

Each IO operations is 1K to 10K times more expensive than any other operation you are doing.

Comment: Thanks. How would you improve it then?